# Second socket.io emit on server side not being received by angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I'm building an application using socket.io to 'match' users in realtime. The idea is that `user a` presses a button to be matched and then when `user b` makes a match request the two are matched by sending io messages to both clients. I'm using AngularJS and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and [bt-fords socket.io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io).

The client makes a request when a controller is entered as shown below:

```
lunchrControllers.controller('UserMatchingController', ['$state', 'socket', 'authService',
    function ($state, socket, authService) {
        socket.emit('match', {userEmail: authService.currentUser()});

        var currEmail = authService.currentUser();
        // only want to catch emits suffixed with the users email
        socket.on('matched' + currEmail, function (data) {
            $state.go('users.matched', {name: data.name})
        });
    }]);
```

where `authService` is used to persist the email of the currently logged in user. On the server side I have code that does a bunch of db work with mongoose (it can definitely be cleaned up) as such:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports = function(socket) {

    socket.on('match', function(data){

        User.findOne({email: data.userEmail}, function(error, user) {
            if(error){
                return
            }

            user.wantsToBeMatched = true;
            user.save(function(err){
                // bleh
            });
        });

        User.find({email: {'$ne': data.userEmail }, wantsToBeMatched: true}, function(error, users){
            if(error || users.length == 0){
                //bleh
                return
            }
            console.log(users);

            User.findOne({email: data.userEmail}, function(error, currentUser) {
                if(error) {
                    return;
                }

                // there is another user who wants to be matched
                users[0].wantsToBeMatched = false;
                users[0].matchedWith = currentUser.firstname;
                currentUser.wantsToBeMatched = false;
                currentUser.matchedWith = users[0].firstname;

                users[0].save(function() {});
                currentUser.save(function() {});

                console.log("I'm gonna emit " + ('matched' + currentUser.email) + " with name = " + currentUser.matchedWith);
                console.log("I'm gonna emit " + ('matched' + users[0].email) + ' with name = ' + users[0].matchedWith);

                socket.emit('matched' + users[0].email, {name: users[0].matchedWith});
                socket.emit('matched' + currentUser.email, {name: currentUser.matchedWith});
            });
        });
    })
};
```

The problem is that only the second user (in this example `user b`) to request a match receives the `socket.emit` from the server. I've tried changing the order of emit messages in the server which didn't help. The console logging logs exactly what I'd expect:

```
I'm gonna emit matcheda@a.com with name = b
I'm gonna emit matchedb@b.com with name = a
```

I've tried using different browsers, using incognito, putting the code on an EC2 instance and having a friend try it out on a different IP and get the same result everytime.
Basically, the problem boils down to the following code not being executed in the browser of `user a`:

```
socket.on('matched' + currEmail, function (data) {
    $state.go('users.matched', {name: data.name})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's the change that I needed to make:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('matched' + users[0].email, {name: users[0].matchedWith});
```

I was missing the word `broadcast`. The reason my previous code wasn't working is because (according to my new understanding of socket.io) `socket.emit` only sends messages to the client which triggered the `socket.on`. To send to other clients the message needs to be broadcasted.